# A problem about limits on C

Tags: limits

Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots, \lambda_n$ be distinct reals.
Prove that, if there are reals $c_i (i=1,2,3,..,n)$ such that $$\lim_{t\to +\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_je^{i\lambda_j t}=0,$$ Prove that, $c_i=0$ for every i.

The 1- and 2- variable case is trivial. However, I encounter several problems when $n\geq 3.$

It seemed that induction might work, but it didn't.

Comment: Ok, @DanielWainfleet, I appreciate the tip.  I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $h>0$ small enough (it we precised later).
For every $k \in [0,n-1]$,
$$\sum_{j=1}^n e^{i\lambda_jkh} c_j e^{i\lambda_jt} 
= \sum_{j=1}^n c_j e^{i\lambda_j(kh+t)} \to 0 \textrm{ as } t \to +\infty.$$
Let $M(h) = (e^{i\lambda_jkh})_{0 \le k \le n-1,1 \le j \le n}$ and $Z(t)$ be the column vector with components $(c_j e^{i\lambda_jt})_{1 \le j \le n}$.
Then $M(h)Z(t) \to 0$ as $t \to +\infty$. Hence it suffices to choose $h$ such that $M(h)$ is invertible. Every small enough $h$ is suitable, since $M(h)$ is a Vandermonde matrix whose determinant is
$$\det M(h) = \prod_{1 \le j<k \le n} (e^{i\lambda_kh}-e^{i\lambda_jh}),$$
so
$$h^{-n(n-1)/2}\det M(h) \to \prod_{1 \le j<k \le n} i(\lambda_k-\lambda_j) \ne 0 \textrm{ as } h \to 0.$$